# When I paste a command instead of typing it why does it not get added to history

Tags: history, bash-history

If I type in a command it is preserved in history, but If I copy and paste a command from other place it is not preserved in history which is annoying if I have to run it again.

I think this happens whatever working environment I'm in, but currently in case it makes a difference I;m connecting to a remote Ubuntu machine via Putty on a Windows machine, and pasting commands from a text document on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be no difference between a copy-and-pasted command and a typed one.  However, if you start a command line with a space, that command is not saved into the history.  It's quite easy when copying and pasting to accidentally put a space at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks I think youve cracked it, my commands are in a text file and indented for readability so often there is a leading space or two.